# how to do I make customized graph in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, graph, xamarin.forms

I want to make graph and chart in Xamarin.Forms. But I don't know how.
I have tryed to find methods or APIs for drawing line, rectangle or manipulate coordinates on view but I couldn't...

I worked with DevExpress Component but there are several limits, so I want to make customized chart and graph.

please give me a way
thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `NGraphics` for xplat drawing in `Xamarin.Forms`  @ https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics

Comment: [OxyPlot contains many different types of axes and series. If you need some functionality that is not included in the library, you can also create a derived class and override the rendering implementation.](http://www.oxyplot.org/)

Comment: what I am looking for is very similar with NGraphics but since I have no much experience on Xamarin, I don't know how use it on Xamarin.Forms. So I will trying to use it and send email to developer of it. Anyway thanks! SushiHangover!

Answer (score 0):

[SciChart](https://www.scichart.com) for Xamarin is also very customizable and extensible. It comes with 20 chart types out of the box, and there is a CustomRenderableSeries type for creating your own chart types.

Have a look at the wide range of [Xamarin Chart Examples](https://www.scichart.com/examples/xamarin-chart/) here.

[image]

SciChart is very fast, able to [draw up to a million points in real-time](https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-chart-performance-demo-example/) on Xamarin iOS & Android. This makes it perfect for Big-data, real-time, scientific and financial apps. It's also very flexible for business apps and supports tooltips, zooming panning, multi axis, legends and more out of the box.

*Disclosure: I am the MD of SciChart*